# Can I reference a script in 'git diff path/to/file' using it's index instead of it's path?

Tags: git, git-diff

I do often want to quickly check on the changes I made. Using `git status` often looks like this:

```
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'develop' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
        modified:   Assets/_Project/Scripts/Controls/ControllerManager.cs
        modified:   Assets/_Project/Scripts/UI/TabletManager.cs

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

To check on the changes I made I would have to use `git diff Assets/_Project/Scripts/UI/TabletManager.cs` with the full path to the file which are often quile long. But since I use this feature quite often with just a few changed script I wonder whether there is something like a quick access option? Maybe by passing the index of the modified file? Something like `git diff 1` to see the changes made in TabletManager instead of the full path.

Comment: With filename completion, it's `git diff A<tab>_P<tab>S<tab>UI/Tabl<tab>` for instance (depending on whether there are other things starting with `A`, etc). Usually not that bad to type in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think git has the quick access option you wish, since most of the times the autocompletion is enough, as @torek told you in the comments.

If you really want this feature, you can create it yourself.

1. First create a folder dedicated to git extensions and `cd` to it
2. Create a script file and name it something like `git-easydiff`. Now I am adding it as a local alias but you can even extend git with custom commands, [here](https://coderwall.com/p/bt93ia/extend-git-with-custom-commands) described how. By the way, a possible script could be:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   changed_files=( $(git diff --name-only) )
   for ((i = 0; i < ${#changed_files[@]}; i++))
   do
       echo "$i - ${changed_files[$i]}"
   done;

   read -p "Index of file to git-diff: "

   git diff ${changed_files[$REPLY]}
   ```
3. And now the alias

   ```
   git config alias.easydiff '!/directory_with_git_extensions/git-easydiff'
   ```

   the `!` at the beginning is necessary because the command is not a git command.

You can call it as `git easydiff`, the output is:

```
0 - file1
1 - file2
Index of file to git-diff: 1
... diff for file2 ...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I already use this script several times a day and it helps so much! :)

Comment: Very happy to know that :)